# viewing attrib.s slots from parent classes in derived classes

Tags: python, attr

How can I view/access the parent class slots from the derived class when using attr?

```
import attr
@attr.s(slots=True)
class a():
   a_val = attr.ib(type=int)

@attr.s(slots=True)
class b(a):
   b_val = attr.ib(type=int)

testb = b(a_val=1, b_val=2)

print(testb.__slots__) #('b_val',), i want to see ('b_val','a_val')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've retrieved the fields with:

`print([elem.name for elem in attr.fields(type(testb))]) # ['a_val', 'b_val']`

alternatively to just see inherited fields:

`print([elem.name for elem in attr.fields(type(testb)) if elem.inherited])`